# How can I find a window with a specific window style? (WS_CHILDWINDOW)

Tags: c++, windows

I've got a specific window with the window style WS_CHILDWINDOW. It's the child window of a window of which I've got the handle already. This window is the second-last one. How do I get it?

It's C++ by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to `EnumChildWindows` posted above, you can use this:

```
HWND first_child = GetWindow(parent_hwnd, GW_CHILD);
HWND last_child = GetWindow(first_child, GW_HWNDLAST);
HWND prev_to_last_child = GetWindow(last_child, GW_HWNDPREV);
```

A drawback of this approach is a possibility of a race if a new child window is added at the end of Z-order between steps 2 and 3. Though in practice it shouldn't be a problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a specific Windows API function for enumerating child windows: EnumChildWindows().  Pass the parent window handle and a callback.  There has to be some "special" about the child window you want to find.  Counting them down in the callback could suffice.  "Previous-to-last" is very possible too, just needs two variables.